# Which method creates the cache directories inside sites/default/files

Tags: 8, files

I am trying to solve the question [SETGID bit gets reset for newly created directories inside sites/default/files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/setgid-bit-gets-reset-for-newly-created-directories-inside-sites-default-files). Please Note the **Update-2** there.

I want to know which method creates the directories like php, css and js inside the `web/sites/default/files` directory. I think the method or function which creates css and js abuse the `chmod` function because only PHP directories obeys the setgid (set group ID) bit rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the method or function which creates css and js abuse the chmod function

There's no code that abuses `chmod` in Drupal. There simply couldn't be - the only interface to the system `chmod` that PHP provides is its own `chmod` function. It's not possible to abuse that function, it only accepts two basic parameters.

It would, of course, be possible to provide extra functionality via a custom PHP extension, but only you could know if you had such a thing installed.

But to answer your specific question:

> I want to know which method creates the directories like php, css and js inside the web/sites/default/files directory

That's [`FileSystem::mkdir`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Amkdir/8.6.x). You can see from looking at the handful of lines of code in there that there's no abuse of `chmod` - just the standard usage.

Comment: Yes but it seems, like Drupal 8.x currently using drupal_mkdir() which is deprecated. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/8.6.x . Can you please have a look on it. So I think this is why the setgid bit doesn't work proerly?

Comment: Does it? I thought most core code was using the service. Regardless, you can invalidate your own conclusion by just reading the code in `drupal_mkdir`